# How to do the same thing as the "compile all" button in Modelsim

Tags: modelsim

In Modelsim there is a "compile all" button that compiles all the files in the project so that they can be simulated. But when the button is pressed it doesn't show what those commands are?

What are the commands to enter in the terminal to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the answer to your question, but you can use `vmake` to make a Makefile and then use ordinary `make` to compile everything. I'll be honest, I never use the Modelsim GUI except to type commands in and set up wave windows.  I hardly ever click anything on the toolbars/menus!